# Custom Adapter with Expandable Listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview, adapter, expandablelistview

Can any one help me with this...I'm trying to implement expandable listview dynamically and i used one of the tutorials (Androidhive) to get familiar to it. My problem is that i am getting my data from parse.com and i want to load it dynamically into the expandable listview. First i am getting data from parse into my object classified by each type and then i suppose to convert that to the expandable listview. What i am stuck in is that i don't know how to pass to the adapter more than 1 object to the child (i have 3 textviews on each child). From the below example i got the data of main road from only to be viewed in the child but i still need to get 2 additional values which i don't know how to achieve.

Hereunder my code for the asynctask :

```
    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        // mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("wait please ...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array

        listviewPostsGet = new ArrayList<listviewPostsGet>();


        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "MainRoadsList");

        try {

            ob = query.find();

            for (ParseObject country : ob) {

                listviewPostsGet map = new listviewPostsGet();
                map.setmainroad(((String) country.get("mainroad")));
                map.setmainroadfrom(((String) country.get("from")));
                map.setmainroadto((String) country.get("to"));
                map.setcategory(((String) country.get("mainroad")));

                listviewPostsGet.add(map);

                listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
                listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();


                String check = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < listviewPostsGet.size(); i++)

                {
                    String XX = listviewPostsGet.get(i).getcategory()
                            .toString();

                    if (!check.contentEquals(XX.toString())) {

                        listDataHeader.add(XX);

                        check = XX;

                         List<String> TTT = new ArrayList<String>();

                        for (int j = 0; j < listviewPostsGet.size(); j++) {


                            String YY = listviewPostsGet.get(j).getcategory().toString();

                            if (YY.contentEquals(XX.toString()))

                            {

                                TTT.add(listviewPostsGet.get(j).getmainroadfrom().toString()+" "+listviewPostsGet.get(j).getmainroadto().toString());

                                listDataChild.put(XX, TTT);

                            }
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        catch (ParseException e)

        {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter1(MainActivity.this,
                listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

Also here is the adapter :

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter1 extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter1(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild ) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listDataChild;
}


public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).toString())
            .get(childPosititon);
}


public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}


public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);



    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.mainlayout, null);
    }

    TextView from = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.fromroad);

    TextView to = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.toroad);

    from.setText(childText);


    return convertView;
}


public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}


public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}


public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}


public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}


public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}


public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Edit :

to be clear , My problem is that I want to assign 3 values from my listviewPostsGet to the expandable listview child and what i can actually achieve is to pass only 1 value which is "Main road from" to the TTT array list then assign it to the corresponding textview on the adapter.

Comment: problem isn't clear enough. maybe you could show it on a sketch - what you are trying to achieve, vs what you get?

Comment: I want to have 3 dynamic values for each child based on parse.com data..I'm able to retrieve all the needed values from parse but what  i just did is to only pass one (main road from) in the arraylist "TTT", i want to pass 3 values and i dont know how to achieve it.

Comment: I will edit the main question to be more clear in my request.

Comment: do you mean that for one of the groups, you get only one child instead of 3 ? if so, have you tried debugging the code and see that it really has 3 items? also, did you check that getChildrenCount returns 3 ? did you check what is going on with getChildView  and getChild ?

Comment: No i got all the needed childs but i have a custom child view with 3 textviews and i can only assign value to 1 textview (which i passed from the array), my question is how to setup an array inside the hashmap to pass the other 2 values to the 2 textviews inside each child?

Comment: well I can see that you are setting only the text of one of them. you should have this hashMap set for each group, so that you could access it, and set the correct String from it into each of the textViews. BTW, you should consider watching "the world of listView" lecture and use the ViewHolder design pattern. it makes things a bit smoother.

Comment: Hey have you finished the work?Is it working as expected?